# Prove convergence of $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x-1}}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I’m faced with a task to prove convergence of $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x-1}}}$ without evaluating the integral. I wasn’t able to find a function $f\left( x \right)$ such that $0\le \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\le f\left( x \right)$ for all $x>1$ and $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{f\left( x \right)dx}$ also converges. I also tried the Limit Comparison Test but, unfortunately, couldn’t find any $f\left( x \right)>0$ such that $\underset{x\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}}{f\left( x \right)}=L\ne 0$ and $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{f\left( x \right)dx}$ also converges.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What about $f(x)=1/x^{5/4}$?

Comment: $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x-1}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{(y+1)\sqrt{y}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\,dz}{z^2+1}=\pi.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_1^{2}\frac {dx} {x\sqrt {x-1}}$ is convergent since $0 \leq \frac {1} {x\sqrt {x-1}} \leq \frac {1} {\sqrt {x-1}}$ for $1 <x<2$.

$\int_2^{\infty}\frac {dx} {x\sqrt {x-1}}$ is convergent since $0 \leq \frac {1} {x\sqrt {x-1}} \leq \frac {2} {x^{3/2}}$ for $2<x<\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x-1}}}=$$
$$=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{dx}{\big(1+\big(\sqrt{x-1}\big)^2 \big)\sqrt{x-1}}}=2\arctan {\sqrt{x-1}} |_1^{\infty}=$$
$$ =2 \big(\frac {\pi}{2}-\big(+0\big) \big)= \pi.$$

Comment: *without evaluating the integral.*

Comment: Thanks! Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}} \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$ for all $x$ belonging to $(1, \frac{3+√5}{2})$.
Also, $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}} \lt \frac{1}{x^{5/4}}$$ for all $x$ greater than $\frac{3+√5}{2}$.
As the integrals of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ and $x^{-5/4}$ are finite over their respective intervals of consideration, the integral converges.